# Error: CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB30 was not declared in this scope

Tags: node.js, canvas

I'm trying to install node-canvas module but I get the following error:
when I do npm install canvas:

```
In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:8:0:
../src/PNG.h: In function 'cairo_status_t canvas_write_png(cairo_surface_t*, png_rw_ptr,  void*)':
../src/PNG.h:139:10: error: 'CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB30' was not declared in this scope
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Same problem on my machine after npm update

Comment: Just pushed version 1.1.1 to npm, which includes a fix for this

Answer (score 9):

It's the problem with the newest version of node-canvas. Install an older one (for example 1.0.4):

```
npm install canvas@1.0.4
```

Comment: I'm using canvas@0.9.0